# How not to allow Facelets sources to be shown in browser by URL

Tags: security, jsf, servlets, facelets

In my `web.xml` I have:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I got some pages, that are stored at my `{project}/webapp/view/` folder

like: `localhost/mybodule/view/index.xhtml`

and able to see all facelets sources. How to make it `404` error instead?

Comment: it seems i found duplication (will check): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662777/hide-xhtml-source-facelets-icefaces

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15433339/1530938

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069640/whitelist-security-constraint-in-web-xml helped. (<auth-constraint/> is important point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my question was related to **JSF** and **404** error throwing.

There is an answer I came up with:

Adding a  setting to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
<param-value>our.company.CustomResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Where: `CustomResourceResolver extends javax.faces.view.facelets.ResourceResolver`

There I would have an overridden method:

```
@Override
public URL resolveUrl(String path) {
 try {
   String fixedPath = "/WEB-INF/pages";

   return getResolvedPath(path, fixedPath);
} catch(IOException e) {
  throw new FacesException(e);
}

}
```

Here we assuming that all our pages are located in `/WEB-INF/pages` folder

Thus, Every time when exception happens it would interpreted as **404**.

And: we should delete `<security-constraint>` from `web.xml` - this guy is good if we want to show user that he does not have access to particular resource, but in our case we do not want showing this. We don't want showing him the fact that this resource exits at all.